# Not able to access the bios menu

Tags: windows-7, window

I am using Samsung Rv511 which has a phoenix BIOS firmware.

I accidentally alter my BIOS settings and enabled the fast boot due to which I am not able to enter BIOS anymore.

When I restart my laptop it says system resuming and after that it's boots from the hard drive. It does not give me and option to enter the BIOS program.

Please suggest what to do to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Bios, the key stroke to enter is still F2 or F10 or whatever. Simply press it *and hold down* before you flip the power on, and it will go in the bios - it just doesn't show you the key on the screen.

If you don't rememeber the key stroke, try the usual, or google it for your model.

Comment: You may also need to force a *full* shutdown before booting: press Windows-R and type `shutdown /s /t 0`.